# Python - Perform Operations for Every Element in a 2D Array and Store it in a new 2D Array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I have 2D array by reading a grey scale image.

```
image = cv2.imread('hurricane katrina 1.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

I want to perform operations on every element in the 2D array and store it in another 2d array. So I did the command below:

```
R = 255 * abs(math.sin(b * image))
```

It throws an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/alyss/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Exercise#4_2.py", line 25, in <module>
R = 255 * abs(math.sin(b * image))
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I know there's a straightforward way to do it in Python without looping. How will I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to perform operations on every element in the 2D array and store it in another 2d array.

Use the NumPy library for performing operations on an N-D array.

EDIT:
Here's a code snippet.

```
255 * numpy.absolute(numpy.sin(b * image))
```

Comment: I am using it. How will I do it?

Comment: @Eliyah A good starting point would be the Numpy documentation. Specifically, the section on [mathematical functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/routines.math.html) seems quite relevant, containing detailed descriptions of each provided function, along with examples of their use.